# OMNI-CHANNEL Queue-Based Routing using APEX

Tags: apex, liveagent, omnichannel, queue, queue-based-routing

I have developed an Apex class with the intention of transferring customer live chat transcripts to a live agent during chat sessions. However, during the implementation process, I have encountered some errors. To be concise, I am currently facing challenges in achieving this functionality. I believe it is achievable, but I require assistance to resolve the issues. Below, I have included the code I have developed and the class responsible for redirecting to a live agent. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or support from anyone with expertise in this area

public with sharing class OmniChannelTransfer {
public class TranscriptInput {
@InvocableVariable(label='Sessionid') //live chat id
public String Sessionid;
}

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Transfer Chat Session to Queue')
public static void chatTransfer(List<TranscriptInput> workItems) {
   List<String> resultMessages = new List<String>(); 
    
   for (TranscriptInput workItem : workItems) {
            // Query for the appropriate queue based on your routing criteria
            Id targetQueueId = determineQueue(workItem);
            if (targetQueueId != null) {
                // Initiate the Live Agent transfer
                startLiveAgentTransfer(workItem.Sessionid, targetQueueId);
                // Success message
                resultMessages.add('Work item ' + workItem.Sessionid + ' successfully routed to queue.');
            } else {
                // Error message when no queue is found
                resultMessages.add('No suitable queue found for work item ' + workItem.Sessionid);
            }
    }  
}

private static Id determineQueue(TranscriptInput workItem) {
    Contact contactRecord = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Name,
                                 Lead_Country_Destination__c, Email
                                 FROM Contact
                                 WHERE Id = :workItem.Sessionid];
     if (contactRecord != null) {  
         bookingReferrence__c booking = [SELECT country__c, No_live_agent__c, live_agent_queue__c   
                                         FROM bookingReferrence__c
                                         WHERE country__c = :contactRecord.Lead_Country_Destination__c]; 
         Group matchingQueues = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND Name = :booking.live_agent_queue__c LIMIT 1];
         return matchingQueues.Id;
     }
    return null;
}

// Replace this method with your Live Agent transfer logic
private static void startLiveAgentTransfer(Id Sessionid, Id QueueId) {
    try {
        // Query for the LiveChatTranscript record associated with the work item (e.g., case or lead)
        LiveChatTranscript transcript = [SELECT Id, chatkey FROM LiveChatTranscript WHERE Id = :Sessionid LIMIT 1];

        if (transcript != null) {
            
            // Get the Live Agent Session Id from the LiveChatTranscript
            String liveAgentSessionId = Sessionid;//transcript.LiveAgentSessionKey;

            // Create a LiveChatVisitor object for the transfer
            LiveChatVisitor visitor = new LiveChatVisitor();
            visitor.SessionKey = transcript.chatkey;
            visitor.TargetQueueId = targetQueueId;

            // Perform the Live Agent transfer
            LiveChatVisitor.transferChat(visitor);

            // Log success or any additional handling as required.
        } else {
            // no LiveChatTranscript record is found for the work item.
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle any exceptions or errors that may occur during the transfer.
        System.debug('Error during Live Agent transfer: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}